# Laravel jobs and views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-jobs

I'm facing a problem i don't really understand it. I'm using Laravel 8 jobs to save my blade view as an html page in my public folder. In my main view I have to load another view and pass it a path to the image which stored in the public folder as follows:

```
@php            
    $path = $book->image;
    //dd($path)
@endphp                                                                                                
@component('report/sales', ['path' => $path])
@endcomponent
```

the $path variable here contains something like
`http://localhost/myapp/src/public/images/books/xyz.jpg` In this view if i do `dd($path)` I get the `http://localhost/myapp/src/public/images/books/xyz.jpg` as expected. Now in sales view I do this:

```
<img src= "{{ asset("/" . $path) }}" alt="some text" width="50%">
```

Now in the produced html file the image is not loaded and src property has the value `http://localhost/myapp/src/public` The strange thing is that when I don't use jobs the html file has this picture. Another weird thing, if I hardcode the value of the variable $path in my main view as:

```
@php            
    $path = "http://localhost/myapp/src/public/images/books/xyz.jpg";
@endphp                                                                                                
@component('report/sales', ['path' => $path])
@endcomponent
```

And I use it with jobs the html file is produced with the picture and everything is fine. Could somebody please help me to understand? Thanks.

Comment: can you post how you uploading your image. post your code here.